# Problem while scraping accordion with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape an accordion on a site so that it retains its hierarchical form.
This is the sanitized html code (I just removed the actual info and replaced it with Xs and Ys and whatever):

```
<div class="card" style="border: none; border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd !important;">
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="settore_01"> <h4>
<p><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#settore01" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="settore01" class="collapsed iq-font-blue" style="width:90%">
01. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </a></p>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="settore01" class="riapri card-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_01_01" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_01_01" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_01_01" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza236_processoPR_01_01" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_01_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
 </h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza236_processoPR_01_01" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=772&id_sequenza=236&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=792&id_sequenza=236&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
 <i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza243_processoPR_01_01" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_01_04" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza243_processoPR_01_01" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=807&id_sequenza=243&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=808&id_sequenza=243&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza242_processoPR_01_01" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_01_05" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza242_processoPR_01_01" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=804&id_sequenza=242&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=805&id_sequenza=242&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=1031&id_sequenza=242&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=806&id_sequenza=242&id_processo=80" class="list-group-item">
 <i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_01_02" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_01_02" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_01_02" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza266_processoPR_01_02" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_02_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
 </div>
<div id="sequenza266_processoPR_01_02" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=914&id_sequenza=266&id_processo=87" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=915&id_sequenza=266&id_processo=87" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
 <h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza267_processoPR_01_02" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_02_02" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza267_processoPR_01_02" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=916&id_sequenza=267&id_processo=87" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
 <h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_01_03" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_01_03" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza264_processoPR_01_03" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_03_02" class="">
wwwwwwwww
 </h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza264_processoPR_01_03" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=900&id_sequenza=264&id_processo=84" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=901&id_sequenza=264&id_processo=84" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza246_processoPR_01_03" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_03_03" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza246_processoPR_01_03" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=821&id_sequenza=246&id_processo=84" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=822&id_sequenza=246&id_processo=84" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_01_04" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_01_04" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_01_04" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza247_processoPR_01_04" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_04_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza247_processoPR_01_04" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
 <li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=823&id_sequenza=247&id_processo=85" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=824&id_sequenza=247&id_processo=85" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza248_processoPR_01_04" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_01_04_02" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza248_processoPR_01_04" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=827&id_sequenza=248&id_processo=85" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=828&id_sequenza=248&id_processo=85" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card" style="border: none; border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd !important;">
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="settore_02"> <h4>
<p><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#settore02" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="settore02" class="collapsed iq-font-blue" style="width:90%">
02. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </a></p>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="settore02" class="riapri card-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_01" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_01" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_02_01" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza136_processoPR_02_01" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_01_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza136_processoPR_02_01" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=401&id_sequenza=136&id_processo=48" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=402&id_sequenza=136&id_processo=48" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza258_processoPR_02_01" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_01_02" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza258_processoPR_02_01" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
 <li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=457&id_sequenza=258&id_processo=48" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=458&id_sequenza=258&id_processo=48" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza139_processoPR_02_01" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_01_03" class="">
wwwwwwwww
 </h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza139_processoPR_02_01" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=411&id_sequenza=139&id_processo=48" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_02" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_02" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_02_02" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza143_processoPR_02_02" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_02_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza143_processoPR_02_02" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=420&id_sequenza=143&id_processo=52" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=422&id_sequenza=143&id_processo=52" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
 <i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza144_processoPR_02_02" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_02_02" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza144_processoPR_02_02" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=426&id_sequenza=144&id_processo=52" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=429&id_sequenza=144&id_processo=52" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=447&id_sequenza=144&id_processo=52" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_03" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_03" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_02_03" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza149_processoPR_02_03" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_03_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza149_processoPR_02_03" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=448&id_sequenza=149&id_processo=53" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=449&id_sequenza=149&id_processo=53" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_04" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_04" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_02_04" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza150_processoPR_02_04" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_04_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza150_processoPR_02_04" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=455&id_sequenza=150&id_processo=54" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_05" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_05" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
 <div id="processiPR_02_05" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza151_processoPR_02_05" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_05_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza151_processoPR_02_05" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=465&id_sequenza=151&id_processo=55" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_06" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_06" class="">
yyyy
</p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_02_06" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza152_processoPR_02_06" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_06_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza152_processoPR_02_06" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=473&id_sequenza=152&id_processo=56" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=474&id_sequenza=152&id_processo=56" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title"><p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right icona-processo" aria-hidden="true"></i><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#processiPR_02_07" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PR_02_07" class="">
yyyy
 </p></h4>
</div>
<div id="processiPR_02_07" class="riapri panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
<h4 class="panel-title3"><p>
<i class="icona-sequenza" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-slash.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#sequenza153_processoPR_02_07" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="seqSQ_02_07_01" class="">
wwwwwwwww
</h4>
</div>
<div id="sequenza153_processoPR_02_07" class=" riapri panel-collapse collapse  " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="seq80-236" style="">
<div class="list-group ada4">
<ul>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=478&id_sequenza=153&id_processo=57" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
<li> <a href="dettaglio_ada.php?id_ada=479&id_sequenza=153&id_processo=57" class="list-group-item">
<i class="icona-ada" aria-hidden="true"><img src="/img/icona-visto.png" width="20px" height="20px"></i> zzzzzzzzz
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ideally, what I'd want is to replicate the nested structure of the accordion with dictionaries, but with my code basically i get ALL of the yyyyyy, all of the wwwww and all of the zzzzzzz elements in every single dictionary. Here's what I did:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://atlantelavoro.inapp.org/atlante_lavoro.php"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

struttura = (soup.find_all(class_="card"))


result = {}


for x in struttura:
    result[x.find('a', {'data-parent': '#accordion'}).text[1:]] = {}
    for e in x.find_all('a', {'data-parent': '#accordion1'}):
        result[x.find('a', {'data-parent': '#accordion'}).text[1:]][e.text[1:]]={}
        for f in x.find_all('a', {'data-parent': '#accordion2'}):
            result[x.find('a', {'data-parent': '#accordion'}).text[1:]][e.text[1:]][f.text[1:]]= []
            for g in x.find_all(class_ = "list-group-item"):
                result[x.find('a', {'data-parent': '#accordion'}).text[1:]][e.text[1:]][f.text[1:]].append(g.text[2:])
```

(The slicing is because i get a "\n" as fist character). I do get what I'm doing wrong, I don't get what else is there to do. I've tried to study Beautiful Soup but to no avail.
Thanks in advance to anyone who's kind enough to help this newbie :D

Comment: "I do get what I'm doing wrong, I don't get what else is there to do." Exactly what should the result be, for the exact input that you have shown us? Exactly what result do you get instead, and how is that different?

Comment: Like I've mentioned in the post:
"i get ALL of the yyyyyy, all of the wwwww and all of the zzzzzzz elements in every single dictionary"
So basically there should be a root key with values 01. x, 02. x, 03. x, and each of these should have inside its own y, w, and z. Instead each one gets every y, every w, every z. 
Not sure if I managed to be understandable, I get that it gets confusing to read :)

Comment: ""i get ALL of the yyyyyy, all of the wwwww and all of the zzzzzzz elements in every single dictionary" " that *doesn't actually allow me to understand* what you get. What would explain what you get is to, e.g., `import pprint` and then `pprint.pprint(result)` after the loop and **copy and paste that output, formatted like multi-line code, in the question**. In programming it is vital to be able to be **exact** about things, and the computer is right there, willing to be exact for you; why go out of your way to lose that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for innermost item (`<li>` tag) in the accordion and the search backwards (using `.find_parent`/`.find_previous_sibling`). For example:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://atlantelavoro.inapp.org/atlante_lavoro.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

out = {}
for item in soup.select('#accordion3 [role=tabpanel]:not(:has([role=tabpanel])) li'):
    tmp = [item.get_text(strip=True)]
    while True:
        p = item.find_parent(role='tabpanel').find_previous_sibling(role='tab')
        if p:
            tmp = [p.get_text(strip=True), *tmp]
            item = p
        else:
            break

    d = out
    for i, v in enumerate(tmp):
        if i == len(tmp) - 2:
            d.setdefault(v, [])
            d = d[v]
        elif i == len(tmp) - 1:
            d.append(v)
        else:
            d.setdefault(v, {})
            d = d[v]

print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "01. Agricoltura, silvicoltura e pesca": {
        "Processo: Coltivazioni agricole, florovivaistiche, forestali e costruzione/manutenzione di parchi e giardini": {
            "Sequenza:Coltivazione di piante erbacee, orticole e legnose in pieno campo e in serra": [
                "ADA.01.01.01 (ex ADA.1.236.772)- Progettazione dell'impianto di coltivazione in pieno campo e in serra",
                "ADA.01.01.02 (ex ADA.1.236.792)- Gestione dei cicli di coltivazione e della produzione in pieno campo e in serra",
                "ADA.01.01.03 (ex ADA.1.236.794)- Lavorazioni del terreno per le coltivazioni agricole",
                "ADA.01.01.04 (ex ADA.1.236.795)- Lavori per la semina e/o il trapianto e/o la piantagione in pieno campo e in serra",
                "ADA.01.01.05 (ex ADA.1.236.796)- Lavori per il governo dello sviluppo delle piante (innesto e potatura) in pieno campo e in serra",
                "ADA.01.01.06 (ex ADA.1.236.797)- Lavori di cura colturale agricola in pieno campo e in serra",
                "ADA.01.01.07 (ex ADA.1.236.798)- Raccolta e prima lavorazione dei prodotti di piante erbacee, orticole e legnose"
            ],
            "Sequenza:Sviluppo e gestione del sistema HACCP e tracciabilit\u00e0 per le produzioni agricole": [
                "ADA.01.01.08 (ex ADA.1.261.889)- Sviluppo del sistema HACCP per le produzioni agricole",
                "ADA.01.01.09 (ex ADA.1.261.793)- Certificazione di qualit\u00e0 e tracciabilit\u00e0 dei prodotti agricoli"
            ],
            "Sequenza:Produzione in vivaio di piante ortofrutticole, ornamentali e fiori": [
                "ADA.01.01.10 (ex ADA.1.241.799)- Lavorazioni preliminari alla produzione di piante ortofrutticole, ornamentali e fiori in piena terra in vivaio",
                "ADA.01.01.11 (ex ADA.1.241.800)- Lavorazioni preliminari alla produzione di piante ortofrutticole, ornamentali e fiori in contenitore fuori suolo in vivaio",
                "ADA.01.01.12 (ex ADA.1.241.801)- Gestione di piante ortofrutticole, ornamentali e fiori in piena terra e in contenitore fuori suolo in vivaio",
                "ADA.01.01.13 (ex ADA.1.241.802)- Produzione vivaistica di materiale di propagazione",
                "ADA.01.01.14 (ex ADA.1.241.803)- Raccolta e prima lavorazione di piante ortofrutticole, ornamentali e fiori in vivaio"
            ],


...and so on.
```

Comment: This works perfectly, it does exactly what I need it to do. The only issue in this is that I understand probably half of the code lol. 
For example:
soup.select('#accordion3 [role=tabpanel]:not(:has([role=tabpanel])) li')
The only other question I can ask is: could you point me to some course? Everything I've tried (and I've tried a lot) is definitely not enough. 
Thanks for the help, I'll study your solution and try to learn from that

Comment: @sickboy83 The `#accordion3 [role=tabpanel]:not(:has([role=tabpanel])) li` is not BeautifulSoup specific - it's just CSS selector. Learning it is handy, you can use it in webdevelopment and in beautifulsoup too. The basic CSS selector guide can be found for example here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php